# Test of the parser not work properly when project builds on travis ci

Tags: java, unit-testing, log4j, travis-ci, assert

Please help. I don't understand what is going wrong.
When I build and deploy my project on the local server all is fine (all test passed). But when it builds on Travis CI I see that error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.XmlParserTest
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/test_logs.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils.XmlParser.<clinit>(XmlParser.java:13)
    at com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.XmlParserTest.testParseXmlFile(XmlParserTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
2017-05-23 15:12:50 INFO  XmlHandler:22 - Start parsing of file...
2017-05-23 15:12:50 INFO  XmlHandler:27 - End parsing of file...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.247 sec <<< FAILURE!
testParseXmlFile(com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.XmlParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.193 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.XmlParserTest.testParseXmlFile(XmlParserTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Results :
Failed tests:   testParseXmlFile(com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.XmlParserTest)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.470 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-23T15:12:50+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/369M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project NC_4_2017_1_project: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/travis/build/NC-4-2017-1/Project/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
The command "mvn clean package" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

This is my log4j configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM
        "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="30"/>
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/test_logs.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

My test:

```
package com.dreamteam.datavisualizator;

import com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils.XmlParser;
import com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils.XmlRow;
import com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils.XmlTable;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class XmlParserTest {

    File file;
    XmlTable testTable;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("test_table.xml");
        file = new File(url.getPath());
        testTable = new XmlTable();
        XmlRow row = new XmlRow();
        row.cells.add("id");
        row.cells.add("title");
        row.cells.add("date");
        testTable.rows.add(row);
        row = new XmlRow();
        row.cells.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1L));
        row.cells.add("test title 1");
        row.cells.add(new Date(1483221900000L));
        testTable.rows.add(row);
        row = new XmlRow();
        row.cells.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2L));
        row.cells.add("test title 2");
        row.cells.add(new Date(1483309235000L));
        testTable.rows.add(row);
        row = new XmlRow();
        row.cells.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3L));
        row.cells.add("test title 3");
        row.cells.add(new Date(1483395635000L));
        testTable.rows.add(row);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseXmlFile() throws IOException {
        XmlTable result = XmlParser.parseXmlFile(file);
        boolean v = testTable.equals(result);
        assertTrue(testTable.equals(result));
    }

    @Test (expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void testParseXmlFileWithWrongPath() throws IOException {
        XmlParser.parseXmlFile(new File("wrong url"));
    }

    @Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testParseXmlFileWithNullArgument() throws IOException {
        XmlParser.parseXmlFile(null);
    }

}
```

My parser:

```
package com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlParser {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XmlParser.class);

    public static XmlTable parseXmlFile(File file) throws IOException {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(file, handler);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            LOGGER.error("File not parsed", e);
            return null;
        }
        return handler.getTable();
    }
}
```

My Handler:

```
package com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XmlHandler.class);

    private XmlTable table = new XmlTable();
    private XmlRow row = null;
    private Object content = null;
    private String typeOfData = "";

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        LOGGER.info("Start parsing of file...");
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        LOGGER.info("End parsing of file...");
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        switch (qName) {
            case "Row":
                row = new XmlRow();
                break;
            case "Data":
                typeOfData = attributes.getValue(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        switch (qName) {
            case "Row":
                table.rows.add(row);
                break;
            case "Data":
                row.cells.add(content);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        String value = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
        switch (typeOfData) {
            case "DateTime":
                try {
                    content = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss").parse(value);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "Number":
                content = BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(value));
                break;
            default:
                content = value;
                break;
        }
        typeOfData = "";
    }

    public XmlTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }
}
```

XmlTable:

```
package com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlTable {
    public List<XmlRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof XmlTable)) return false;

        XmlTable xmlTable = (XmlTable) o;

        if(rows==null||xmlTable.rows==null) return false;
        if(rows.size()!=xmlTable.rows.size()) return false;

        for (int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++){
            if (!rows.get(i).equals(xmlTable.rows.get(i))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return rows != null ? rows.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

XmlRow:

```
package com.dreamteam.datavisualizator.common.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlRow {
    public List<Object> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof XmlRow)) return false;

        XmlRow row = (XmlRow) o;

        if(cells==null||row.cells==null) return false;
        if(cells.size()!=row.cells.size()) return false;

        for (int i=0; i<cells.size(); i++){
            if (!cells.get(i).equals(row.cells.get(i))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return cells != null ? cells.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem with test fixed (different time zone). But I still have problem with logs